# Получение атрибута rel у видимых div'ов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

HTML:

```
<div id="example4" class="example">
    <div id="drag4">
        <div id="sector" rel="0_1"></div>
        <div id="sector" rel="1_1"></div>
        ...
        <div id="sector" rel="10_1"></div>
        <div id="sector" rel="0_2"></div>
        ...
        <div id="sector" rel="10_10"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<span id="kkasdjc"></span>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x1 = $('#example4').offset().left + $('#example4').outerWidth() - $('#drag4').width();
    var y1 = $('#example4').offset().top + $('#example4').outerHeight() - $('#drag4').height();
    var x2 = $('#example4').offset().left;
    var y2 = $('#example4').offset().top;
    $("#drag4").draggable({
        containment: [x1, y1, x2, y2]
        //containment: 'window'
    });

    //изначальная позиция
    $("#drag4").css({
        left: '-724px',
        top: '-107px'
    });

    //Закончено перемещение, 
    $('#drag4').bind('dragstop', function (event, ui) {
        $('#kkasdjc').text($("#drag4").position().left + '  ' + $("#drag4").position().top + ' ||| x1=' + x1 + ' y1=' + y1 + ' x2=' + x2 + ' y2=' + y2);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrh1eLge/2/).

Как мне получить атрибут `rel` у всех `div`'ов, которые в данный момент показаны в блоке `<div id="example4">`, при прекращении перетаскивания?

То есть всех `div`'ов, которые мы видим в момент события `dragstop`.

Comment: Блоки, которые мы видим, или которые видны в `#drag4`? Это не одно и то же - мы можем видеть `#drag4` не полностью.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте JQuery offset([документация](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)).
Получив смещение элемента #example4 и его размеры будет очень легко вычислить видимые нам элементы внутри него.
Ниже приведен очень грубый, но демонстрирующий работу offset() пример.

Еще вы допустили ошибку используя одинаковый #sector более чем для одного элемента. Атрибут id должен быть уникальным, иначе возникнут проблемы с работой скрипта. Подробнее про него можно прочитать [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/id)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var x1 = $('#example4').offset().left + $('#example4').outerWidth() - $('#drag4').width();
  var y1 = $('#example4').offset().top + $('#example4').outerHeight() - $('#drag4').height();
  var x2 = $('#example4').offset().left;
  var y2 = $('#example4').offset().top;
  $("#drag4").draggable({
    containment: [x1, y1, x2, y2]
      //containment: 'window'
  });

  //изначальная позиция
  $("#drag4").css({
    left: '-724px',
    top: '-107px'
  });

  //Закончено перемещение, 
  $('#drag4').bind('dragstop', function(event, ui) {
    var bloks = $('.sector'),
      arr = []
    bloks.each(function(key, el) {
      var $el = $(el),
        offsetEl = $el.offset();
      if (offsetEl.top > 0 && offsetEl.top < 445 && offsetEl.left > 0 && offsetEl.left < 445) {
        $el.css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
      } else {
        $el.css('background-color', 'white');
      }
    });
    $('#kkasdjc').text($("#drag4").position().left + '  ' + $("#drag4").position().top + ' ||| x1=' + x1 + ' y1=' + y1 + ' x2=' + x2 + ' y2=' + y2);
  });


});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.example {
  min-width: 500px;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: ridge medium #0F3;
}
#drag3,
#drag4 {
  width: 1920px;
  /*Общая масимальная ширина карты*/
  height: 1800px;
  /*Общая масимальная высота карты*/
  background: url(/dark-textile-background.jpg) repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  /* убираем горизонтальные отступы */
  line-height: 0;
  /* ...и вертикальные в некоторых браузерах */
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  /* переубеждаем webkit'ы */
}
div.sector {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  display: -moz-inline-stack!important;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  //display:inline;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="example4" class="example">
  <div id="drag4">
    <div class="sector" rel="0_1"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="1_1"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="2_1"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="3_1"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="4_1"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="5_1"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="6_1"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="7_1"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="8_1"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="9_1"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="10_1"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="0_2"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="1_2"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="2_2"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="3_2"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="4_2"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="5_2"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="6_2"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="7_2"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="8_2"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="9_2"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="10_2"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="0_3"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="1_3"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="2_3"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="3_3"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="4_3"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="5_3"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="6_3"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="7_3"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="8_3"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="9_3"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="10_3"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="0_4"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="1_4"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="2_4"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="3_4"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="4_4"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="5_4"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="6_4"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="7_4"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="8_4"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="9_4"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="10_4"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="0_5"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="1_5"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="2_5"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="3_5"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="4_5"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="5_5"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="6_5"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="7_5"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="8_5"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="9_5"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="10_5"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="0_6"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="1_6"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="2_6"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="3_6"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="4_6"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="5_6"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="6_6"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="7_6"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="8_6"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="9_6"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="10_6"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="0_7"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="1_7"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="2_7"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="3_7"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="4_7"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="5_7"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="6_7"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="7_7"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="8_7"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="9_7"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="10_7"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="0_8"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="1_8"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="2_8"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="3_8"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="4_8"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="5_8"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="6_8"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="7_8"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="8_8"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="9_8"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="10_8"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="0_9"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="1_9"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="2_9"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="3_9"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="4_9"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="5_9"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="6_9"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="7_9"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="8_9"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="9_9"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="10_9"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="0_10"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="1_10"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="2_10"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="3_10"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="4_10"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="5_10"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="6_10"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="7_10"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="8_10"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="9_10"></div>
    <div class="sector" rel="10_10"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<span id="kkasdjc"></span>
```